# How do I work out the future position of a moving object?

Tags: java, math, physics

I am creating a little game and I have a photon torpedo which is being fired from a ship towards a target. Now as the speed of the torpedo is slow the ship will never hit any targets if they're moving and I want to fix this. I have drew up multiple theories and mapped out lots of mathematical stuff to find out the best way to accomplish this and in the end I deduced the following:

1. List item
2. I find the time it takes for the photon torpedo to get to the target.
3. I find how far the target will have traveled in the time it takes for the torpedo to arrive.
4. I then find the distance between the new position of the target and the original ship.
5. this then gives me the opportunity to use the Cosine rule (SSS) to find out the trajectory at which the bullet needs to be fired to have a much higher chance of hitting.

Here is a digram:

[image: A diagram of my problem]

Now the only problem that I need to rotate line a to the correct orientation as by default it's parallel to line c which messes up the entire equation. Can anyone help with this? And also if you can think of a better way to find the new position suggestions are very welcome :)

Comment: Probably belongs on: http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I beg to differ, as this is a coding question. However, as it is a mixture of coding and physics it doesn't really matter. But thanks for your input.

Comment: You haven't asked anything implementationally or algorithmically specific. Your question is a good question. It's just a physics question and not a programming question. You'll also likely get better answers more quickly if you ask there. Once you have your formula, then you can come here for implementation help.

Comment: What about math.stackexchance?

Comment: Based on the FAQ pages for both math and physics, your question belongs on the physics site.

Comment: Ok, I shall vacate to there then. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to come back here if you need assistance with your Java implementation. Good luck.

Comment: I can't believe this question was closed, I was expecting a java implementation!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like game is in 2D. Now, taking all world coordinates:

```
Target Position: {xt, yt}
Target Velocity: {vxt, vyt}
Ship Position:   {xs, ys}
```

Now, lets say you hit a bullet in direction `{bx, by}` it is a directional vector or unit vector. The bullet has speed `sb`. Therefore, in time `t'` spacial coordinates of bullet and target would be:

```
Target New Position: {xt + vxt*t', yt + vyt*t'}
Bullet New Position: {xs + bx*sb*t', ys + by*sb*t'} ( bullet starts from ship)
```

Since, at this time both bullet and target must be at one location only then we can say bullet has hit the target. Therefore, we can substitute new target position to be equal to new bullet location (after time t'):

```
xt + vxt*t' = xs + bx*sb*t'
yt + vyt*t' = ys + by*sb*t'
```

As I said earlier, `bx` and `by` are directional vector, therefore `bx^2 + by^2 = 1`

```
(xt + vxt*t' - xs)/(sb*t') = bx
(yt + vyt*t' - ys)/(sb*t') = by
bx^2 + by^2 = 1
```

Therefore, after squaring and adding them, you will get:

```
(yt + vyt*t' - ys)^2 + (xt + vxt*t' - xs)^2 = (sb*t')^2
```

This is a quadratic equation with one variable: `t'` solve it and then you could find `bx` and `by`.

Comment: I don't have the targets velocity tracked. And the function which calculates its position can only run once so a velocity cannot be deduced, SO i cannot really use this method :(

Comment: @ShaunWild In your diagram it looks like the target is moving at 5m/s? Regardless, if the target is moving, but at an unknown speed, you can't figure out how far ahead to aim.

Comment: What's that `4 m/s` in the diagram?

Comment: @ShaunWild I thought 4 m/s in diagram is target velocity in direction of C  to B.

Comment: We can assume the speed is always either going to be 4m/s or 0. which is basically tracked by the target. If worst come to worse I'll implement a new movement system into my game which allows ships velocities to be tracked using vectors and what not.

Comment: I admit it's badly  labelled as I kinda rushed it :P but the 4m/s represents the target ships velocity.

Comment: Yes, it is required to know the direction in which target is moving otherwise it is impossible to solve for future position.